# gradle, could not find property in buildSrc

Tags: gradle

I made custom task, name MySqlTask.groovy

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

public class MySqlTask extends DefaultTask {
  def hostname = 'localhost'
  def sql

  @TaskAction
  def runQuery() {
   //to do something...
  }
}
```

And, I put this file in rootProject/buildSrc/src/main/groovy.

My build file is customtasksourcetree.gradle.

> task createDatabase(type: MySqlTask) {   sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT
>   EXISTS example' }

When I run gradle with customtasksrc.gradle then raise error like this.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/need4spd/Programming/Java/workspace/gradleTest/customtasksourcetree.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleTest'.
> Could not find property 'MySqlTask' on root project 'gradleTest'.
```

I have read that, my custom task file in buildSrc will compiled and add to classpath during build time automatically.

I can see compiled MySqlTask.class in buildSrc/build/classes.

What's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is due to the fact that you haven't imported MySqlTask in your build script

Comment: Do I need import my custom task in my build script? There is no mention about it in http://www.gradleware.com/registered/books/building-and-testing/tasks.html. I'll try find about it. Thanks!.

Comment: You (only) have to use an import if your task class has a `package` statement. Apparently yours doesn't. Try if `gradle --stop` followed by a clean build helps. Also try to delete the `.gradle` directory.

Comment: @yongseokJang that link is dead, any new working ones you can update to?